# Can the "Target directory" for the Pycharm "Generate Test" feature be configured to use the source subfolders structure as the default?

Tags: pycharm

While there are differing preferences about whether to put pytests in a similar hierarchy as the original source - vs just throwing them all into a single flat `tests` directory, my team is clear on using the former approach.

I do not see how to achieve that from the `Create test` dialog without manually adding the hierarchy to the `Target directory`:

[image]

A secondary issue here is that the intended target folder probably does not already exist - so it is necessary to manually create the folder structure anyways. So then the `Generate test` provides little initial value.

Is there a way to configure the `Create test` to put the new testcase for a class ion the `my.package` module into the `tests/my/package` directory by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think at the moment this is not feasible. I was looking for this functionality myself, but it seems to not be present (compared to e.g. IntelliJ IDEA).

There is an open issue on Pycharm issue tracker, it does not seem to have gotten any traction. I hope they do implement it at some point though.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-37441/Remember-target-directory-for-test-generation